# Print rest of list in iteration with indeterminate length in same paste function

Tags: r, list

I am new to R and need help with this iterable. Here is my code:

```
vec1 <- c("John", "Cat")
vec2 <- c("Matthew", "Dino", "Dog", "Bird")
vec3 <- c("James", "Snail", "Worm", "Frog", "Dragon")
list1<- list(vec1, vec2, vec3)

printer <- function(list1) {
  for (item in list1) {
    print(paste(paste(item[1], "'s pets are", sep = ''), paste(item[2:length(item)], sep = ' ')))
  }
}

printer(list1)
```

The result

```
[1] "John's pets are Cat"
[1] "Matthew's pets are Dino" "Matthew's pets are Dog"  "Matthew's pets are Bird"
[1] "James's pets are Snail"  "James's pets are Worm"   "James's pets are Frog"   "James's pets are Dragon"
```

I'm trying to have the pet names all print in the same line, but they keep printing separate.

Answer (score 0):

In the second `paste`, it should be `collapse` instead of `sep`

```
for (item in list1) {
    print(paste(paste(item[1], "'s pets are", sep = ''), 
       paste(item[2:length(item)], collapse = ' ')))
  }
```

-output

```
[1] "John's pets are Cat"
[1] "Matthew's pets are Dino Dog Bird"
[1] "James's pets are Snail Worm Frog Dragon"
```

or use `toString`)

```
for(item in list1) print(paste0(item[1], "'s pets are ", toString(item[-1])))
```